# Undo an old commit that has been push and only keep parts of the changes

Tags: git

I want to go to an old commit.
Parts of the old commit I want to keep and parts I want to delete.
After deleting the part of the commit that I don't want, I want to go back to the head of the master branch.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer : I can't quite say from your description what you want to do. Below are the two most probable interpretations I could come up with. Tell us more and I'll edit.*

---

**If you want to modify a commit in past history**, this is a big and very inconvenient process, involving rewriting all history down from the modified commit. Extremely problematic when you share the repo with anyone, and even when alone not at all a light operation. Let us know if this is the case but I will assume the second case.

---

**If you want to use (part of) the changes brought with a specific commit**, after having tweaked it to suit your specific needs (here, excluding part of the changes), you can :

```
git cherry-pick -n <commitHash>
```

It will not yet create a commit on the tip of the current branch, it will bring in the working tree the changes from this commit and you'll have the opportunity to add/remove/modify anything you want and *then* commit.

Answer (score 0):

git revert reverted all changes in my old commit.
It did not remove the changes just u committed my changes. From there I was able to remove the changes I did not want. So the revert is a partial revert.

git revert